# Terminal insert A B C D on shift+arrows. Solution?

Tags: command-line

I'm new to Ubuntu and I don't know how I did it, but now when I try to select a text with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+[**left/right**]arrow keys, it inserts me "D C"(letters). I look up on Google for an hour and I haven't found anything really to help me.

I have installed Ubuntu with WUBI and I'm speaking about <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> terminal.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've found a workaround to copy text from gnome-terminal. It is via `screen`.  <sup>Credit goes to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/312215/1039893)</sup>

1. Type `screen` in the terminal
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd>-<kbd>[</kbd> to Enter the copy mode
3. Move your cursor to the desired start location.
4. Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to start copying.
5. Press and hold <kbd>→</kbd> or <kbd>←</kbd> key to select text
6. Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> again to stop copying.
7. Then move your cursor the the location you want to paste.
8. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd>-<kbd>]</kbd> to paste the text.

For a more complete screen tutorial, see [this page](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/34).

Answer (score 4):

OK, here is some historical background. Terminal comes from times from *before* the ubiquity of the <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> shortcuts. In fact, ctrl-C has already had a meaning for a very long time: in a terminal, it is used to interrupt the current foreground process in a terminal. And Ctrl-D is for sending EOF (end of file).

See for your self; start a program that would take a lot of time and produce a lot of output, such as `find /`, and press Ctrl-C to interrupt it. Start a program that expect some input, such as `cat > testfile.txt`, type some text, and then press Enter (for newline) and Ctrl-D such that the program thinks "end of file, fine" and exits.

Moreover, copy and paste could (and can) be achieved in X in a much simpler way. The moment that you have selected any text with your mouse – just selected, no keys pressed – it has been copied to the X clipboard. Whenever you now press the *right* mouse button, without any keyboard shortcut, the text will get pasted. No need for shortcuts at all. This works not only in terminal, but also in other programs – try it!

However, you cannot use this method to copy anything other than simple text; to copy graphics, files etc. you need ctrl-c and ctrl-v.

Nonetheless, to achieve *some* compatibility with the modern dogma, you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> in a terminal.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure this is default behaviour; it happens on my terminal, too.  But you can select text with the mouse and then paste it by center-clicking.  This means clicking both the left and right buttons at once!

If you want to select all the text you can do so under Edit --> Select All.  And if you're new to the terminal you can learn more about certain programs with the `man` command.  For example, `man script` should give information about a session-recording program that may be interesting to you.

Comment: this is  not the default behaviour in ubuntu shift+arrow keys selects text this is the default behaviour